# Entity Framework Core 1.0.2(in VS 2017), Error- The directory name is invalid

Tags: entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2017

[image]

Getting error while executing Migrations.
Exception: The directory name ... is invalid

Comment: Why you are using version 1.0.2 version instead of 1.1.x ?

Comment: I updated entity framework version to 1.1, but still that issue exists.

Comment: Can you tell which directory?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have your DBContext class and migrations in your startup project? I had the same error when using separate project for migrations and web app. The EF project was looking up some settings from the web project and everything worked fine in VS 2015. After upgrade to VS 2017 something has changed and my path to settings file was no longer valid resulting in "The directory name ... is invalid" error. After fixing the path everything works fine.